# Significance of Objective-C objc_image_info version on ABI?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, abi, objective-c-category

I found that some of our iOS apps have linker warnings like this:

```
Incompatible Objective-C category definitions. Some category metadata may be lost. 'path/to/libSome.a(Some.o)' and 'path/to/libPrebuilt.a' built with different compilers
```

After reading [this](https://www.dynamicdispatch.io/blog/Objective-C-Incompatible-Category-Definitions/) post, I've checked `objc_image_info` of the prebuilt libraries using `otool` and some of them has `flags 0x20 OBJC_IMAGE_IS_SIMULATED` whereas libraries built using latest Xcode (11.1) has `flags 0x40 OBJC_IMAGE_HAS_CATEGORY_CLASS_PROPERTIES`.

Does these difference of `objc_image_info` really matters over Objective-C ABI? Is it possible to introduce app crashes?

Comment: What are the CPU architectures of those libraries?

Comment: We are targeting aarch64-apple-ios, as no iOS 11+ devices has armv7.

Comment: OK but what CPU architectures are those libraries built for?

Comment: Prebuilt libraries are fat binaries for many architectures including armv7, armv7s arm64.